# SP2013 Export-SPWeb and Import-SPWeb preserve meta data

Tags: export, import, content-and-structure

I want to move a list / library from one site collection to another. I tried to use `Export-SPWeb` and `Import-SPWeb` PowerShell commands, however the imported list items doesn't not preserve metadata like `Created, Created by, Modified by`.

I already used `-IncludeVersions All -IncludeUserSecurity`

Is it not supported by design?

UPDATED:
After trying the Content and Migration tool. I found that if the ModifiedBy and CreatedBy user of the original item not exist in current AD, the copied/moved items will change the ModifiedBy and CreatedBy to the user who run the operation.

Answer (score 0):

It is the limitation of the export and import command. But there are couple of things you can try

- use 3rd party tools, which preserve the metadata while moving the contents.i.e sharegate or metalogix
- if it is with in same site then use content structure option to move the list
- i am not sure but garylapoint has custom powershell commands for export n import.http://www.falchionconsulting.com/PowerShellViewer/Default.aspx

Comment: I used Content and Structure tools to move items to another site. The items are created by one user who always leave company. The AD already deleted his account. Before moving item, it can still show the original user name in the item property on the original list. However after move the items using Content and Structure tool, the  Created and Modified time stamp preserved but the CreatedBy and ModifiedBy become my account (the one that run Move operation)

Comment: You really should add this to your initial question as it changes its scope.

Comment: I faced this issue after trying Waqas Sarwar MCSE's suggestion that use Content and Structure tool. I just want to point out the Content and Structure does not preserve metadata in some situation.

Comment: all the options / workaround having the limitations but 3rd party tools is give 100%